# recursive sql query call

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion

I have the following table which represent streets from corners to corners

```
street    |  from        |  to 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
street1   |  node11      |  node2222
street1   |  node2222    |  node111
street1   |  node111     |  node4
street1   |  node4       |  node1212
street1   |  node1212    |  node6
street1   |  node6       |  node7
street1   |  node7       |  node8
street99  |  node2222    |  node111
street99  |  node111     |  node4
```

Id like to be able to get the data of street1 with one recursive query 
with the "from" equal "node2222"   and the last data will have a "to" equal to "node6"
The result have to be sequential , the "to" of one line become the "from" of the next line.

I can do that in a basic query but it will only return 1 data so I have to basically call it 4 times sequentially to have my whole sequence

```
select street, from , to where street = 'street1'  AND from = 'node2222'
```

on second call of the query,  with the result from call #1

```
select street, from , to where street = 'street1'  AND from = (call #1).to
```

and so on ...

The result of the "recursive" query Id like to have will be something like this if it find all the nodes or it will return what it found so far:

```
street    |  from        |  to 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
street1   |  node2222    |  node111
street1   |  node111     |  node4
street1   |  node4       |  node1212
street1   |  node1212    |  node6
```

Is it possible to do that in SQL within one query

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
select distinct street,
  "from", 
  "to"
From YourTable
where street='street1'
connect by nocycle "from" = prior "to" and "to"<='node6'
start with "from"='node2222'
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6f8d0/10)

Comment: Hi @TechDo ,   the query is almost correct .  In fact my node are not sequential and not uniqe, I correct my data to reflect that.  I added 2 line for street99 that had the same nodes, that represent a street parallel to street1

Comment: I modified your fiddle to reflect the data I changed here, as you can see the result generate some extra data, Here is the neww fiddle :     http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6f8d0/4